# Frames in HTML of fixed length

Tags: html, frame, frameset

I have an HTML page with three frames in it.
I have given the size of frames as 150px, 300px and 150px.

If I want to change the frame size of 3rd one to 500px, the other 2 frames become smaller.
I want instead the page should come up with scroll bar and frames to be of
150px, 300px, 500px repectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use   < iframe > instead of < frameset >

```
< iframe class="one" src="one.html" >< /iframe >
```

Now we can change width and height with this class.

Comment: Yes, iframe is better way to do that. But you need to specify the position attribute in style for each frame. Otherwise, frame gets placed below each other if it exceeds the width of browser window and you want horizontal scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Give the width and height of iframe as style.

**eg:**  `<iframe src="http://www.codeigniter.in" style="height:500px;width:500px;float:left;"></iframe>`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving size in pixel, like 150px, try to give it in percentage.
Example

```
<FRAMESET cols="20%, 80%">
```

If you want frames below each other i.e. vertically, then you can use `rows` attribute of frameset.

Comment: Then it will distribute the 100% of page into two with 20 and 80.  It won't append scroll-bar. And I want frames of fixed size.

Comment: I have given example as 20, 80. You can use as per your requirement. And for vertical splitting use rows=xx

Comment: Suppose a normal page is of 300px. I want frames of 150px, 300px, 500px, then I want page to increase itself (by adding scroll bars) and become of 950px.

Comment: Then in that case, you should use "px" only, and for scolling purpose, go through the properties of Frameset tag, As @Leo mentioned

Comment: Refer to another answer added by me

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the iframes(HTML 5 feature), You can mention the position in the style.
I have written the sample html page for this, and it works as required. Horizontal scrolling with increasing the width of the frames is working as expected.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe width="150px"></iframe>
        <iframe width="300px"></iframe>
        <iframe width="2000px" style="position: absolute"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Go through the following links for `position` in the style of iframes
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Comment: Here you can add name to each frame and mention the source for each frame